# Bearings GCSE Exam question ples help

Tags: geometry

A ship sails 12km on a bearing of 050 degrees then 20km on a bearing of 100 degrees. It then sails directly back to its starting position. Calculate this distance to 1dp.

What i did:
[image]

I got the distance as 23 which is wrong idk y.

I just measured the distance.

Thank You and Help is appreciated

Comment: It would help it you show your calculations.  How can you expect us to tell you what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did?

Comment: I just measured the distance and drew bearings.

Comment: You mean you drew a picture and measured the segment with a ruler?  That won't be accurate enough.  Besides, I'm sure you are expected to solve the problem with trigonometry.  Go back over your lessons.

Comment: Ohhhhh ok I just wanted to check if the bearing shape is right?

Comment: Well, the angles are all right.  (I mean the numbers, I have no way of actually measuring the angles) and if the line length are $12$ and $20$ then you are right.  What is the answer supposed to be?

Comment: The answer should be 29.2 km

Comment: Then you must have gotten the lengths wrong.  There's no way you should be off by that much.  (Or the book answer is wrong.)

Comment: I get $23.835$  I think the answer in the book is wrong.

Comment: OH SO IM RIGHT WOO oh ok

Comment: The correct answer would appear to be 29.2 to me and can be obtained by using the cosine formula.

Comment: @MarkBennet I see that I made a mistake in my drawing.  You're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cosine law: if $a$, $b$, $c$ are the sides of a triangle opposite to angles $A$, $B$, $C$ then 
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A\\b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos B\\c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C$$
In your case $a=20$, $c=12$ and $B=130^{\circ}$ so you can use the second equation to find $b$.